# Moving a Git install on Linux

Tags: linux, git, terminal

It would seem I've installed git in the following directory:

```
/root/bin/git
```

(Not quite sure how, to be honest.)

And therefore rendered git unaccessible to anybody other than the root user.

Can I simply move the files to `/usr/bin` (or similar) or do I have to uninstall and reinstall.

If uninstall is required, how should I do that?

Comment: Have you tried just moving the files to `/usr/bin`?

Comment: @regulatethis Nope. Should I have done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In many system `$HOME/bin` is put to `$PATH` using either `.bashrc` or `/etc/bashrc`. Thats why in your case only `root` can able to access git as its installed in `root`s home. But no one else.

The only solution is to remove that git. Install git system wise.

```
yum install git-core
```

or

```
apt-get install git-core
```

If git was installed in `/root` as prefix you might find `usr`, `etc`, `lib` etc directories in `/root` folder. Remove them too. Also make sure any other software didn't get installed like git.

Comment: Hopefully, the fact that /root/bin is not in the path is not the only reason why other users cannot access it …

Comment: `~` means current users home. This can only be accessed by current user.

Comment: Thanks @shiplu.mokadd.im, I removed all those files and reinstalled. `yum install git-core` didn't work, though. Had to install from a gzip. `which git` now returns `/usr/local/bin/git`, which I assume is infinitely better.

Comment: @Chris `yum install git` should work then.  one user can not access other users home. even they can access they can never access to admins home. `/root` is admins home.

Comment: @Chris well, ideally users should be unable to access other users home directories, even more so if the other user is ``root``.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, git has following files installed

```
extra/git       /etc/
extra/git       /etc/rc.d/
extra/git       /etc/conf.d/
extra/git       /etc/conf.d/git-daemon.conf
extra/git       /etc/rc.d/git-daemon
extra/git       /usr/
extra/git       /usr/bin/
extra/git       /usr/lib/
extra/git       /usr/share/gitk/lib/
extra/git       /usr/share/gitk/lib/msgs/
extra/git       /usr/share/gitk/lib/msgs/fr.msg
extra/git       /usr/share/gitk/lib/msgs/ru.msg
extra/git       /usr/share/gitk/lib/msgs/pt_br.msg
extra/git       /usr/share/gitk/lib/msgs/ja.msg
extra/git       /usr/share/gitk/lib/msgs/sv.msg
extra/git       /usr/share/gitk/lib/msgs/hu.msg
extra/git       /usr/share/gitk/lib/msgs/es.msg
extra/git       /usr/share/gitk/lib/msgs/it.msg
extra/git       /usr/share/gitk/lib/msgs/de.msg
extra/git       /usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi
extra/git       /usr/share/gitweb/static/
extra/git       /usr/share/gitweb/static/gitweb.js
extra/git       /usr/share/gitweb/static/gitweb.css
extra/git       /usr/share/gitweb/static/git-logo.png
extra/git       /usr/share/gitweb/static/git-favicon.png
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git.pm
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/SVN/
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/SVN.pm
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/I18N.pm
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/IndexInfo.pm
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/SVN/Memoize/
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/SVN/Editor.pm
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/SVN/Migration.pm
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/SVN/Log.pm
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/SVN/Ra.pm
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/SVN/Prompt.pm
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/SVN/GlobSpec.pm
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/SVN/Fetcher.pm
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/SVN/Utils.pm
extra/git       /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Git/SVN/Memoize/YAML.pm
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man3/
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man5/
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man7/
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man7/gitcli.7.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man7/gitcore-tutorial.7.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man7/gitcredentials.7.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man7/gitcvs-migration.7.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man7/gitdiffcore.7.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man7/gitglossary.7.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man7/gitnamespaces.7.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man7/gitrevisions.7.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man7/gittutorial-2.7.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man7/gittutorial.7.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man7/gitworkflows.7.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man5/gitattributes.5.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man5/githooks.5.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man5/gitignore.5.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man5/gitmodules.5.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man5/gitrepository-layout.5.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man5/gitweb.conf.5.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-add.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-am.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-annotate.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-apply.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-archimport.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-archive.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-bisect.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-blame.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-branch.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-bundle.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-cat-file.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-check-attr.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-check-ref-format.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-checkout-index.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-checkout.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-cherry-pick.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-cherry.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-citool.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-clean.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-clone.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-column.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-commit-tree.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-commit.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-config.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-count-objects.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-credential-cache--daemon.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-credential-cache.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-credential-store.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-credential.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-cvsexportcommit.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-cvsimport.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-cvsserver.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-daemon.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-describe.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-diff-files.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-diff-index.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-diff-tree.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-diff.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-difftool.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-fast-export.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-fast-import.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-fetch-pack.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-fetch.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-filter-branch.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-fmt-merge-msg.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-for-each-ref.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-format-patch.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-fsck-objects.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-fsck.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-gc.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-get-tar-commit-id.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-grep.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-gui.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-hash-object.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-help.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-http-backend.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-http-fetch.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-http-push.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-imap-send.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-index-pack.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-init-db.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-init.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-instaweb.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-log.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-lost-found.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-ls-files.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-ls-remote.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-ls-tree.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-mailinfo.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-mailsplit.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-merge-base.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-merge-file.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-merge-index.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-merge-one-file.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-merge-tree.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-merge.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-mergetool--lib.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-mergetool.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-mktag.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-mktree.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-mv.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-name-rev.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-notes.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-p4.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-pack-objects.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-pack-redundant.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-pack-refs.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-parse-remote.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-patch-id.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-peek-remote.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-prune-packed.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-prune.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-pull.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-push.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-quiltimport.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-read-tree.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-rebase.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-receive-pack.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-reflog.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-relink.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-remote-ext.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-remote-fd.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-remote-helpers.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-remote-testgit.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-remote.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-repack.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-replace.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-repo-config.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-request-pull.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-rerere.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-reset.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-rev-list.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-rev-parse.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-revert.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-rm.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-send-email.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-send-pack.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-sh-i18n--envsubst.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-sh-i18n.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-sh-setup.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-shell.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-shortlog.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-show-branch.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-show-index.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-show-ref.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-show.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-stage.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-stash.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-status.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-stripspace.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-submodule.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-svn.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-symbolic-ref.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-tag.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-tar-tree.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-unpack-file.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-unpack-objects.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-update-index.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-update-ref.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-update-server-info.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-upload-archive.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-upload-pack.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-var.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-verify-pack.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-verify-tag.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-web--browse.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-whatchanged.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git-write-tree.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/git.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/gitk.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man1/gitweb.1.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man3/Git::SVN::Editor.3pm.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man3/Git::SVN::Memoize::YAML.3pm.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man3/Git::SVN::Ra.3pm.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man3/Git::I18N.3pm.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man3/Git::SVN::Prompt.3pm.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man3/Git::SVN::Fetcher.3pm.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man3/Git::SVN::Utils.3pm.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/man/man3/Git.3pm.gz
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/pt_PT/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/vi/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/da/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/nl/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/sv/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/it/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/de/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/zh_CN/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/is/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/is/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/vi/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/
extra/git       /usr/share/locale/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo
extra/git       /usr/share/git-core/templates/
extra/git       /usr/share/git-core/templates/branches/
extra/git       /usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/
extra/git       /usr/share/git-core/templates/info/
extra/git       /usr/share/git-core/templates/description
extra/git       /usr/share/git-core/templates/info/exclude
extra/git       /usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
extra/git       /usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/commit-msg.sample
extra/git       /usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/post-update.sample
extra/git       /usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
extra/git       /usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/pre-commit.sample
extra/git       /usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/pre-rebase.sample
extra/git       /usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample
extra/git       /usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks/update.sample
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/
extra/git       /usr/lib/systemd/
extra/git       /usr/lib/systemd/system/
extra/git       /usr/lib/systemd/system/git-daemon@.service
extra/git       /usr/lib/systemd/system/git-daemon.socket
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers-0.1.0-py2.7.egg-info
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/git/
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/__init__.pyc
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/util.pyc
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/__init__.py
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/util.py
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/git/__init__.pyc
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/git/repo.pyc
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/git/exporter.pyc
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/git/importer.pyc
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/git/non_local.pyc
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/git/git.pyc
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/git/__init__.py
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/git/exporter.py
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/git/git.py
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/git/importer.py
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/git/non_local.py
extra/git       /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/git_remote_helpers/git/repo.py
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-http
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-am
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-bisect
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-difftool--helper
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-filter-branch
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-lost-found
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-merge-octopus
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-merge-one-file
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-merge-resolve
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-mergetool
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-pull
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-quiltimport
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-rebase
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-repack
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-request-pull
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-stash
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-submodule
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-web--browse
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-add--interactive
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-difftool
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-archimport
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-cvsexportcommit
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-cvsimport
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-relink
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-send-email
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-testgit
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-instaweb
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-mergetool--lib
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-parse-remote
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-rebase--am
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-rebase--interactive
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-rebase--merge
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-i18n
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-gui
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-gui--askpass
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-citool
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-cvsserver
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-add
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-annotate
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-apply
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-archive
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-bisect--helper
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-blame
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-branch
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-bundle
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-cat-file
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-check-attr
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-check-ref-format
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-checkout-index
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-checkout
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-clean
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-clone
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-column
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-commit-tree
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-commit
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-config
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-count-objects
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-credential
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-describe
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-diff-files
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-diff-index
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-diff-tree
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-diff
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-fast-export
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-fetch-pack
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-fetch
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-fmt-merge-msg
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-for-each-ref
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-fsck
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-gc
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-grep
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-hash-object
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-help
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-index-pack
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-init-db
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-log
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-ls-files
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-ls-remote
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-ls-tree
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-mailinfo
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-mailsplit
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-merge
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-merge-base
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-merge-file
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-merge-index
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-merge-ours
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-merge-recursive
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-merge-tree
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-mktag
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-mktree
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-mv
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-name-rev
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-notes
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-pack-objects
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-pack-redundant
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-pack-refs
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-patch-id
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-prune-packed
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-prune
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-push
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-read-tree
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-receive-pack
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-reflog
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-ext
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-fd
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-replace
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-rerere
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-reset
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-rev-list
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-rev-parse
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-revert
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-rm
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-send-pack
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-shortlog
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-show-branch
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-show-ref
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-stripspace
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-symbolic-ref
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-tag
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-tar-tree
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-unpack-file
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-unpack-objects
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-update-index
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-update-ref
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-update-server-info
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-upload-archive
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-var
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-verify-pack
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-verify-tag
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-write-tree
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-cherry
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-cherry-pick
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-format-patch
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-fsck-objects
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-get-tar-commit-id
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-init
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-merge-subtree
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-peek-remote
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-repo-config
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-show
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-stage
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-status
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-whatchanged
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-ftp
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-ftps
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-p4
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-credential-store
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-daemon
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-fast-import
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-imap-send
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-i18n--envsubst
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-show-index
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-fetch
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-push
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-credential-cache
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-credential-cache--daemon
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-shell
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/git-upload-pack
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/araxis
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/bc3
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/codecompare
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/defaults
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/deltawalker
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/diffuse
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/ecmerge
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/emerge
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/kdiff3
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/kompare
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/meld
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/opendiff
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/p4merge
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/tkdiff
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/tortoisemerge
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/vim
extra/git       /usr/lib/git-core/mergetools/xxdiff
extra/git       /usr/bin/git
extra/git       /usr/bin/git-cvsserver
extra/git       /usr/bin/gitk
extra/git       /usr/bin/git-receive-pack
extra/git       /usr/bin/git-upload-archive
extra/git       /usr/bin/git-upload-pack
extra/git       /usr/bin/git-shell
```

so its not just simple as moving `/root/bin/git`, its better you install git using package manager.

**Ubuntu**

```
$ apt-get install git
```

**Fedora**

```
$ yum install git
```

For Mac & windows: see [Downloads Page](http://git-scm.com/downloads). using prebuilt packages is preferred way to install git

Answer (score 0):

Installing `git` places the lot of internal commands in `$PREFIX/libexec/git-core` (where `$PREFIX` is as set by `./configure --prefix=...`), and the `git` executable runs them from there. It also looks for configuration in `$PREFIX/etc/`, and so on. Can't just move the executable around, and moving the installed files won't help either.